# Set image height and width android..!

Tags: android

In my app i am inserting image from sdcard to imageview.
How can i set image width=window width and image height will set automatic by Aspect ratio.

After this i will transform image by matrix.

i am using this code

```
int height;
int width;

String[] template_array;
ImageView imgTemplate;
int position = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery_image);


    height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    InitUI();
    // InitPager();
    DisplayImage();
    SetonClickListners();
}
```

Comment: Nothing is automatic. You'll have to calculate the aspect ratio yourself. I'd suggest you use Picasso instead, it'll save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: @Pztar If you think you need Picasso for this you really don't understand the built in image view.  Its a simple matter of setting the scale type.

Comment: @Pztar can you tell me OR suggest any tutorial by which i can calculate the aspect ratio and set my image...?

Answer (score 0):

Set the image view's width to MATCH_PARENT, height to WRAP_CONTENT, and scaleType to centerInside.  This will make it scale keeping aspect ratio, have a width of the full screen, and stop scaling the image such that it fits on the screen.